# How to capture free speech from user in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to capture free speech from the user in Dialogflow.

Let's imagine the following conversation:

```
User: I want to order a pizza
Agent: What type of pizza would you like to order?
User: Chicago Pizza.
Agent: What time works best for you?
User: 6 PM.
Agent: Okay, would you like to add a note to the restaurant?
Yes -> User: Yes, please.
       Agent: Please, tell me your note
       User: <Free speech, user may say whatever he/she wants or feels necessary for his/her order>
       Agent: Copy that. You ordered a Chicago pizza and it will delivered at 6 PM. We have also sent your note to the restaurant.
No ->  User: No.
       Agent: Okay, you ordered a Chicago pizza and it will delivered at 6 PM.
```

How can I receive or capture that sort of speech from the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @sys.any entity. Use follow-up intent with sys.any if user says yes after `Agent: Okay, would you like to add a note to the restaurant?` . You can get free speech as string by doing this and use it as note.

Also, you may consider to look here:

[Agent Design](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-design)